# How to rename files with only 1 occurrence?

Tags: powershell, rename

The problem is I need to rename files.

Original name:

> Patient Data - John Smith - John Varner

I have tried this code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "John ","Dr. " }
```

But the problem is it also replaces the other name to Dr. that looks like this:

> Patient Data - Dr. Smith - Dr. Varner

But I need it to look like this:

> Patient Data - Dr. Smith - John Varner

Oh just to let you know I'm a noob when it comes to Powershell I just copy codes from the internet. So I dont have any idea what code to use. Please help me with the exact code I'm gonna use. Thank you so much

Comment: Are all file names in this format? : Patient Data - Dr Name - Another Name ?

Comment: Hi yes. they are all in the same format

Patient Data - Dr. Name - Name

I just want 1 occurrence when renaming. I dont want powershell to rename also the patient's name.

Comment: It looks like this question has been closed. This is not quite a duplicate, you have a little more going on than what was in the dupe. But this should work for you: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % {
    $drName = (($_ -split "-")[1]).Trim()
    $nameReplace = $drName -replace "$(($drName -split " ")[0])", "Dr."
    Rename-Item -NewName $nameReplace
}`

Comment: Hi I've tried your code. Nothing happens

The thing is, The file name starts with a name not Dr. Name - Patient Name

Example

John Smith - John Doe

should be like this:

Dr. Smith - John Doe

Is there any code that I could use to just have one occurence of renaming for the whole file name. 

get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "John ","Dr." }

that is the code I am using

Comment: @jrider I fail to see how this question would not be a duplicate, since in both cases only the first occurrence of a particular substring should be replaced.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The problem is I dont know how to apply the answered question to my coding. I'm sorry I'm a noob when it comes to this

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Respectfully, the answer is to replace a static word in a string. I think that is a big difference for a beginner. With that point, if you still see it as a dupe, I can respect that.

Comment: It's `-replace '(.*?)SEARCH_TERM(.*)', '${1}REPLACEMENT_TERM${2}'`, so in your case: `-replace '(.*?)John(.*)', '${1}Dr.${2}'`.

Comment: If you want to replace varying names after the first hyphen, then the code would have to look somewhat like this: `-replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2}'`.

Comment: @jrider Yes, I still think it's a duplicate, since the only difference is in what substring to match. My previous comment should address that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I can agree with your point, it should be a duplicate. Sorry for the confusion... Next time, more coffee first.

Comment: I've tried this:

get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname $_.name -replace '(.*?)John(.*)', '${1}Dr.${2}'

and this:

-replace '(.*?)John(.*)', '${1}Dr.${2}'

Still not working or does not do anything.

Also tried this:

-replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2}'

Comment: The argument to the parameter `-NewName` needs to be in curly brackets, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: `get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '(.*?)- \w+(.*)', '${1}- Dr.${2} }`

Is this correct?

Comment: @GabrielBalenton There's a single quote missing after `${2}`, but other than that yes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers OMG thank you soooo much for the help!! Now my only problem is how do I incorporate this code without the extra spaces. Because after the "Dr. " there's an extra space.